# Is this SystemRestore available?

Tags: backup, data-recovery

I saw something similar in Windows for Ubuntu at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemRestore.

I was wondering if it has been available now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most accidental system crashes and failures due to broken packages can be solved by booting into recovery mode. The option 'fix broken packages' in recovery mode is very powerful. I have solved most system issues through it. Most of the configuration files are in /etc directory, so they can be easily backed up by a crontab job. I have tried using system restore on MS windows to recover badly crashed systems, and have failed many times. comparatively I have found the ubuntu tool I have mentioned above more powerful.